# How to know if I run python from Textmate/emacs?

Tags: python, emacs, textmate, environment

I use TextMate to debug python script, as I like the feature of using 'Command-R' for running python from TextMate, and I learned that emacs provide similar feature.

I need to know if the python is run from command line or from TextMate/emacs. How can I do that?

### ADDED

I use TextMate for python coding/debugging, and it's pretty useful. But, sometimes I need to run the test using command line. I normally turn on debugging/logging mode with TextMate, and off with command line mode. This is the reason I asked the question. Also, I plan to use emacs for python debugging, so I wanted to ask the case for emacs.

I got an answer in the case with emacs, and I happen to solve this issue with TextMate.

1. Set variables in Preferences -> Advanced -> Shell Variables, and I found that TM_ORGANIZATION_NAME is already there to be used. So, I'll just use this variable.
2. Use this variable, if os.environ['TM_ORGANIZATION_NAME']: return True

I guess the shell variable from TextMate disappear when I'm done using it.

Comment: What exactly do you intend that your script do differently if it is run from the command line vs. the editor?

Comment: That sounds like a source of endless debugging and confusion.  Do one thing makes sense.  Do things based on implicit context -- scary.

Comment: @kindall : I use TextMate for coding/debugging, and I set debugging mode on to print out more detailed information when I use TextMate. I just wanted to turn on debugging mode automatically when I'm running Python on TextMate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For Emacs: If python is run as an inferior process, then the environment variable [`INSIDE_EMACS`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Interactive-Shell.html) will be set.

From docs:

> Emacs sets the environment variable
>   INSIDE_EMACS in the subshell to a
>   comma-separated list including the
>   Emacs version. Programs can check this
>   variable to determine whether they are
>   running inside an Emacs subshell.

Answer (score 1):

`sys.argv` will tell you how Python was invoked. I don't know about TextMate, but when I tell Emacs to eval buffer, its value is `['-c']`. That means it's executing a specified command, according to the man page. If Python's run directly from the command line with no parameters, `sys.argv` will be `[]`. If you run a python script, it will have the script name and whatever arguments you pass it. You might want to set up your python-mode in Emacs and whatever the equivalent in TextMate is to put something special like `-t` in the command line.

That's pretty hackish though. Maybe there's a better way.

Answer (score 1):

From [the docs](http://docs.python.org/library/sys.html#sys.path) for `sys.path`:

> As initialized upon program startup,
>   the first item of this list, path[0],
>   is the directory containing the script
>   that was used to invoke the Python
>   interpreter. If the script directory
>   is not available (e.g. **if the
>   interpreter is invoked interactively
>   or if the script is read from standard
>   input), path[0] is the empty string**,
>   which directs Python to search modules
>   in the current directory first. Notice
>   that the script directory is inserted
>   before the entries inserted as a
>   result of PYTHONPATH.

So

```
if sys.path[0]:
    # python was run interactively
else:
    # python is running a script.
```

Or, for example, from the IPython prompt (inside Emacs):

```
In [65]: sys.path
Out[65]: 
['',  <-------------------- first entry is empty string
 '/usr/bin',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/scikits.statsmodels-0.2.0-py2.6.egg',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/pyinterval-1.0b21-py2.6-linux-i686.egg',
  ... ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Command-R to run the script directly

Use Shift-Command-R to run the script from terminal.